How to add Document Library programically?
I need to add Document Library to my project. How could I do this from Visual Studio. I see the template for Document Library is 101. How Could I do it to set Document Library on Schema, Could You plis tell me how could I do this ?

What is the version of your SharePoint product? On-premise like 2016, 2019, or SharePoint Online in Microsoft 365?

You are looking for PnP Provisioning Engine.
See latest Provisioning Schema for details and example. Latest schema has a full sample available.

No it for Sharepoint Online. I look for Sharepoint 2019.

PnP supports SP-2019 as well. See installation reference.
